# How to get queue size of the Azure Service Bus using .NET API in C#

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am working on a **.NET Core project**. I am trying to connect to the service bus queue using a connection string. I am able access the service bus with QueueClient using the API function 'new QueueClient(< connection string >, < queue name >). However Queue client does not have any functions to get the size / message count.

I have tried the **NamespaceaManager.CreateFromConnectionString** (< connection string >) function, but looks like its been deprecated in .NET Core (and it keeps throwing dependency errors).

I tried the **Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent** package but could not get it to work either.

Are any of these the right way to do it, and is there any other way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NamespaceaManager` is not available with the new Azure Service Bus client library. It's planned to [add support](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65#issuecomment-338874419) for some of the functionality `NamespaceManager` used to provide, but not queue size. For that, you will need to use Azure Monitor service that can provide message counts and entity size ([additional information](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/reading-azure-service-bus-metrics) and a [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/Management/Metrics/)). Also, entity metrics via REST API [were deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2018/05/11/azure-service-bus-deprecating-entity-metrics-rest-api/) and Azure Monitor should be used instead.

Comment: I am trying to follow the code on the sample. I am not able to locate client id, tenant id and secret. I do have a connection string that was generated by the service bus. Is there any way to find this information or use the connection string instead for authentication?

Comment: For management operations, you can't use the current version of the current client. It will come later. Anything else, you can already do.

Comment: Thanks that helped!